# KIX barcode in ZPL

Tags: python, barcode, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm trying to print out an addresslabel on a Zebra (ZPL) printer. Since we are sending within the Netherlands, it is required to add a KIX barcode to our labels, so the equipment for sorting the documents can read the zipcode and housenumber. Our labels look a bit like this:
[image: KIX]

I can create a KIX barcode in ZDesigner 2, but I can't figure out how I can change the data of the barcode, since it's encoded in Z64 and I couldn't find out how to decode/encode this.

There is also a Windows Font available for this (.ttf), but I don't know how I can get this font to my Zebra printers

I did try a service on Docker hub, which generates an image of the KIX barcode, but I'm pretty sure it can be done without converting the barcode to an image.

I prefer to solve this with plain ZPL, because I want to be able to replace printers without any installation process. I'm using Python. Hope somebody can help!

Comment: ZPL doesn't support KIX barcodes (see the [ZPL Programming Guide](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) [PDF] for supported bar code formats). As such you probably do need to produce the barcode graphics separately. The easiest solution is probably using a python library with Zint bindings such as [pyzint](https://github.com/Pavkazzz/pyzint).

Answer (score 0):

Seems the barcode symbiology is not terribly complicated. You could probably make your own algorithm. It's just simple lines and spacing; not terribly complex.ZPL gives you the capability of making lines pretty easy. You can keep track of the character number, and add X pixels * character number for positioning. Use a replace function to replace letters with the line code you come up with.

Check out the details on the [RM4SCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RM4SCC) sybology. The KIX variant seems simpler to implement as it doesn't need a check digit.

For testing, [scandit](https://www.scandit.com/) offers a free iPhone scanner that should read RM4SCC. Once you have RM4SCC working, just remove the parts that KIX doesn't include.